# Macro to force uppercase not working on specified range

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro in Excel to automatically capitalize text entered in a range of cells.

I found code online that works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C10")) _
Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

It functions fine, but I get a value mismatch error when I copy or paste multiple cells into the specified range. So I tried using this code instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("$A$1:$C$10")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Target
        If Not r.HasFormula And r.Value <> "" Then
            r.Value = UCase(r.Value)
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly even when copying and pasting, but it applies to the entire spreadsheet, even though the `r` variable has a range set on it. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Try `For Each r In Range("$A$1:$C$10")` or use the intersection between `Range("$A$1:$C$10")` and `Target` (not sure which one you want)

Comment: you want to use `For Each r in Intersect([A1:C10], Target)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to properly combine techniques of two code samples. Second code lacks intersection feature, while the first one lacks iteration among a range of inserted cells. Try this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Magic_Range As Range, Iterator_Range As Range
    Set Magic_Range = Range("$A$1:$C$10")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Magic_Range) Is Nothing Then
        For Each Iterator_Range In Application.Intersect(Target, Magic_Range)
            If Not Iterator_Range.HasFormula And Iterator_Range.Value <> "" Then
                Iterator_Range.Value = UCase(Iterator_Range.Value)
            End If
        Next Iterator_Range
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```